# How to download all repository tree files and folders?

Tags: webserver, repository

first of all excuse me for asking this way but I didn't know another way to express what I need. If anyone can edit the question, I would be very pleased.

Often searching for some materials through internet I finish opening some pages (repositories) whose contain all the information that I need but I don't know how to download all those files & folders. It is the possibility to download them one by one, but doing this for a big repository is almost impossible. For example these URL: [OpenSusse Repository](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/) or [Primefaces](http://repository.primefaces.org/org/) .

Can anyone help please?

Comment: I am using Windows 7. Is there a tool or software that I can use?

Comment: @DanD. I read a little and wget did the work, can you post your comment as an answer so I can accept that. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps `wget`. There is even wget for Windows.

And here is [curby](https://cur.by/)'s `wget-mirror` which I use:

```
#
#
#   get prerequisites
# don't get parent   \
#                 \   \
wget -N -l inf -r -np -p $1
#   /   /      /
#  /   |      /
# |    |     recursive get
# |   infinite recursion
#don't get unless newer than local
```

Comment: For windows x64 I used http://www.alexlomas.com/blog/2005/08/64_bit_wget_for_windows/   Placed the .exe in System32 folder.

Comment: @AlbanoVito it looks like it doesn't work with https.

Answer (score 1):

Try this tool:

http://www.httrack.com/

It is a freeware tool that allows you to recursively download an entire website (including images, linked files etc) and make a local copy.